# Compiling Heimdall with Cmake on Windows 10

Tags: android, cmake

It's my first time using Cmake, and everything was going fine, until I used the final command it began to build my environment. If someone could please just tell me what this message means and how I can fix it.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljasper
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwebp
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwebp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
heimdall-frontend/CMakeFiles/heimdall-frontend.dir/build.make:338: recipe for target 'bin/heimdall-frontend.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/heimdall-frontend.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:198: recipe for target 'heimdall-frontend/CMakeFiles/heimdall-frontend.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [heimdall-frontend/CMakeFiles/heimdall-frontend.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Makefile error.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11936640/4180965)

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to compile Heimdall on Windows 8, and got same error.

I had was missing Jasper, and Webp, and got those to link with packman. Try to run this line:

> pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libwebp mingw-w64-x86_64-jasper

That solved this for me.