# recipe for target 'main.o' failed

Tags: gcc, pyqt4, mingw32, python-sip

I am trying to install SIP to be able to install PyQt on my Windows system. I'm following a guide "https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2010-May/026642.html" but @ step 8

```
Then launch : C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe
```

I'm receiving following error. I have no clue what to do due to little experience with C. After research I found this similar error [Cygwin - Makefile-error: recipe for target `main.o' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932809/cygwin-makefile-error-recipe-for-target-main-o-failed) but apparently the cause should be different because the solution there doesn't apply with my case.

```
C:\Users\timpi\Downloads\sip-4.18.1\sip-4.18.1>"C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/timpi/Downloads/sip-4.18.1/sip-4.18.1/sipgen'
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o main.o main.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o main.o main.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/timpi/Downloads/sip-4.18.1/sip-4.18.1/sipgen'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, you have the directory right there in the error message, as well as the file names. I think next step is pretty obvious...

Comment: Well it's not that the main.c is missing (see below). The main.o should be output and not yet be present right? What file is missing according to you? It's not obvious to me

C:\Users\timpi\Downloads\sip-4.18.1\sip-4.18.1\sipgen>dir m*


   
    14-Sep-16  01:02 AM            15,189 main.c
    14-Sep-16  10:19 PM            19,962 main.obj
    14-Sep-16  10:56 PM             1,260 Makefile
    14-Sep-16  01:02 AM    <DIR>          metasrc
                   3 File(s)         36,411 bytes
                   1 Dir(s)  414,746,742,784 bytes free

Comment: That was the next step I meant, it was missing ftom the question. You should edit it in with formatting. But consider using bash/sh to investigate instead pf cmd.exe. It could be issue with backslashes.

Comment: The problem was that I was focused on the missing main.c main.o files but actually he couldn't find 'gcc'. The error message could have been more clear. Thank anyway

Comment: @tim_p Hi. i am having a similar problem. What do you mean with "couldn't find 'gcc'"? And how did you solve it? If you could please answer this it would be really helpful.

Comment: @umbe1987 I'm not sure why I only now received a notification for your question. Anyway the problem that he couldn't find the executable gcc. This is the C compiler. I had to download it via the MinGW libraries. Hope you didn't wait  2 months to make progress on this issue :)